# What do you call an "atheist" who might believe in an afterlife?

Tags: single-word-requests, religion

Is there a term for someone who proclaims they don't believe in an afterlife but they are not sure whether the supernatural exists?

I don't mean *agnostic*. Atheists  don't believe in a deity, but an atheist could believe in an afterlife.

Comment: Is there a word for a fear of non-existence and NOT  necessarily a fear of death?

Comment: Your second question (in the comments) should get its own question. :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Umm, the title is the exact opposite of the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, but which comment are you referring to?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The question asks "is there a term for someone who... don't believe in an afterlife...?"  The title you added asks for a term for someone who does believe in an afterlife.

Comment: @BenVoigt aah I see you're talking about the edit I made. When was it, eleven days ago? The second question was a quote lifted directly from the OP; yes, it's still there. The original title, I felt was too vague, I changed it to reflect the context. The OP didn't disapproved, in fact it appears he's vanished.

Answer (score 3):

**Spiritual** would be the best way to describe yourself.

There is a movement to try and differentiate the terms spirituality vs religion (Sources are numerous, [here's one](http://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/mistic/mistic_10.htm))

Also, there is a belief system being adopted called [Spiritual but not religious (SBNR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritual_but_not_religious) that is used to self-identify a life-stance of spirituality that rejects traditional organized religion as the sole or most valuable means of furthering spiritual growth.

However, there are several beliefs that you could identify with.

1. [Thanatism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thanatism) (as pointed out by another user) where the basis of belief is life comes *before* death, not after it (no afterlife). The term *Thanatism* comes from [thanato](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thanato-), which means *death*. After an individual dies, their soul becomes one with nature. *Thanatism* is type of spiritual belief and not a religion.

> I'm a *thanatist*. I live life to its fullest.

[Esotericism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esotericism) or [esoteric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esoteric), which means that you believe in something that few others do. The term translate to 'inner-circle' and is used to define a small group of individuals that believe in the same thing.

> I don't subscribe to any mainstream religious thoughts. My beliefs are esoteric.

[Theosphical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theosophy) whereby you use your own beliefs to justify certain facts for your spiritual or religious benefit. One example of this is Christians trying to justify dinosaurs existing during the early history of the world.

> I believe in everything the Bible says except about heaven and an afterlife.

[Mysticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysticism) is "a constellation of distinctive practices, discourses, texts, institutions, traditions, and experiences aimed at human transformation, variously defined in different traditions." Due to its diverse interpretation, you can incorporate a believe (or lack thereof) about the afterlife.

> I don't believe in an afterlife for the soul because I'm a mystic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's been a long day.

Comment: And I've edited far too many posts today :)

Comment: I'm a born-again Christian myself and I believe in what the Bible indicates to be true but I also believe Dinosaurs existed and the Earth is millions of years old. I read some Catholic Bishop declared the Earth was 6000 years old starting from Adam and Eve being expelled from the Garden of Eden BUT he should have counted the expance of time before they left Eden..What I was asking about was a term for someone who does not believe in an afterlife but is vague about the supernatural. Thanatism might work. I coined a word for this 'Finitism'. Is there a word for fear of non-existence?

Comment: @user128932 Thanatism is a pagan belief system. Life *before* death, which is considered blasphemous in Christianity because it completely casts out the idea of an afterlife. "There is no heaven." [Agnosticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosticism), which is *the truth values of certain claims—especially claims about the existence or non-existence of any deity, as well as other religious and metaphysical claims—are unknown or unknowable.* The fear of non-existence is different from being vague about the supernatural.

Comment: @user128932 There is also the term [ignosticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignosticism) which is *the idea that every theological position assumes too much about the concept of God and other theological concepts; including (but not limited to) concepts of faith, spirituality, heaven, hell, afterlife, damnation, salvation, sin and the soul.* Perhaps this is more of what you're looking for? There is also a difference between fear of death (end of existence) and fear of no afterlife (fear of nonexistence).

Comment: Is there a word for someone who is aware of the reality of death but is vague about whether there is an after-life or if the supernaturel exists? Someone who puts off such questions or represses them?

Comment: @user128932 The answer to the first question is an agnostic. The answer to the second question is a tricky one because it implies some sort of fear of it, in which case *thanatophobic* is probably the closest word.

Comment: @user128932: It seems worth mentioning that "finitism" has already a well-established technical meaning among mathematicians. It refers to a philosophy of mathematics that accepts only those mathematical objects that can be constructed from the natural numbers in a finite number of steps.

Comment: @DanFox That's actually pretty interesting. A mathematical concept that can be adopted as a spiritual sense. Grounds for a good question if you ask me. What word can mean a mathematical form of enlightenment...

Comment: Is there a word for fear of non-existence? Is thanatophobic only a fear of death (end of existence) and not 'fear of non-existence' ? Is Thanatos a Greek word for death? Is there a Greek word or phrase meaning non-existence ?

Comment: @user128932 'Nullitatiphobia' = fear of non-existence. 'Nullitatis' = non-existence.

Comment: THANK you for the info. ; I've never heard of this term.

Comment: Is nullitatiphobia a 'legitimate' word ; note I'm not trying to criticize ,I've just never heard of it. Is it in the Webster's dictionary. The thing is if there is a legitimte word for the fear of non-existence ( and never being able to exist again) and it is recognized not just in some dictionary of difficult or unused expressions then why don't any academics or philosophers use it.

Comment: @201044 Wow, I forgot this. No, it isn't a 'legitimate' word in English. It's a neologistic word. It's not recognized by others probably because there's no reason for it to exist. In this case the requirement was very niche, there are probably a lot of synonyms that convey the same idea that are more common and accepted.

Comment: What are those synonyms?

Comment: @201044 No idea. I made up a word that perfectly defines the prerequisites by cobbling together the Latin roots. Perhaps there are more common words in the French of German languages that are accepted in English.

Comment: @201044 Two years on, but I think I have that synonym you wanted now: The word is: _Apeirophobia_ and it is from the Greek ápeiros, "infinite, boundless". It is defined as the fear of infinity or eternity. Although _nullitatiphobia_ more exactly defines this concept because of its near-literal transcription, _Apeirophobia_ is quite commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Someone needs to redefine atheism or come up with another term to describe those who believe in the soul and/OR an afterlife type existance/persistance but not in an all powerful, all knowing, God-creator.  Maybe Taosim comes closest and Buddhism comes in second, but each has it's own strict tenets of belief and structure as do most religions.

I'd go with "Taoistic" for now.

Comment: This is closer to a comment than to an answer to the poster's question. Unfortunately, as a newcomer to English Language & Usage, you aren't eligible to post comments yet; but if you accumulate 50 points from asking and answering questions here that get upvoted (5 points per question upvote and 10 points per answer upvote), you will earn the privilege of commenting on other users' questions and answers.

Comment: One can be spiritual and atheistic. Atheism only refers to non belief in a god/gods. The term "atheist" already covers the people you describe.

Comment: @SvenYargs this is a great comment.  would you like to add it to [this answer](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/6825/106801) on meta?

Comment: @erich: Please feel free to make it your own and alter it in any way you like, if you feel that it may be of use on meta. I greatly appreciate your efforts to come up with thoughtful and meaningful responses to newcomers at EL&U, and to resist the urge to be dismissive of efforts that run afoul of the site's standards in some way. I have to say, though, that the "from asking and answering questions here that get upvoted" wording in my comment is a bit too awkward to become a boilerplate response. It should say something like "from questions and answers you post here that get upvoted."

Answer (score 0):

look at "thanatism". it means the belief that the soul dies with the body, hence no afterlife.

Comment: That isn't quite right. Thanatism states that the soul dies is returned to nature. So, when you die you become one with nature. The soul itself does not 'die' in the fatalistic sense, but merely the cognitive version of the individual that dies becomes with with everything.