# What is a word that describes a belief (or nonbelief) in an afterlife?

Tags: word-choice

What is a word that describes a belief (or nonbelief) in an afterlife?

Comment: You mean agnostic ?  : 
 a person or pertaining to a person  who holds that the existence of the ultimate cause, as a god or God, and the essential nature of things are unknown and unknowable.

Comment: I find fault with your premise.  The first *homo sapien* was not born believing in the concept of an afterlife.  The concept of an afterlife was likely created by the Egyptians, and has been with us ever since.  Your question requires additional constraints in order to be meaningful.

Comment: @Nick2253, The first recorded example in history of something is not the same thing as the first occurrence of that thing.

Comment: @Josh61, a person may be agnostic about many or most things, such as God, but not agnostic about an afterlife.  See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164317/what-do-you-call-an-atheist-who-might-believe-in-an-afterlife

Comment: @colinator Obviously they are different.  My point is that written rejection of something is not a meaningful concept.  Only in the 20th and 21st centuries have people written about their rejection of the [IPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_Pink_Unicorn).  The number of useful conclusions I can draw from that information is small.

Comment: A skeptic : 1) a person who questions the validity, authenticity, or truth of something purporting to be factual, esp. religion or religious tenets.
2)  a member of a philosophical school of ancient Greece which maintained that real knowledge of things is impossible.

Comment: @Nick2253, I have the feeling that you'd have less of a problem with my question if I had left out the context completely.  It's not part of the question, so the faultiness of the premise does not affect the meaningfulness of the question.  I was just trying to provide an example of where such a word could be used.

Comment: @cowlinator: A search for "philosophical naturalism" might turn up what you're looking for, since that philosophy goes hand-in-hand with a rejection of the afterlife. Other terms that might help in your searches: deism, apostasy, doctrine of immortality.

Comment: BTW, @Nick2253 - it is with the Cro-Magnons that we see the first evidence of the regular and elaborate practice of ritual burial, which imply belief in an afterlife. The Cro-Magnons (*circa* 40,000 kyrs ago) preceded the Egyptians by tens of thousands of years.

Comment: I don't recall ever running across a term with this meaning.  "Atheist", "agnostic", et al imply, to one degree or another, a disbelief in a deity, but that does not really imply belief or non-belief in an afterlife (as commonly understood).  You have an interesting question -- why is there no such term for such a fundamental human concept?

Comment: @Nick2253 - I agree with Little Eva.  The concept of an afterlife of some sort seems to be built into human nature.  I suspect that a sentient being inherently has difficulty comprehending the idea that he or a companion could simply transition to a state of non-existence, with total nothingness afterwards.  Religion is probably rooted more here than in the need to understand "why".

Comment: @cowlinator and Josh61: Agnosticism maintains that we have no grounds on which to accept or reject metaphysical existence. We do not and we cannot know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a philosophical issue that I think would long predate anything we could call "English"

Comment: @FumbleFingers, can you explain?

Comment: @LittleEva Belief in an afterlife is not a prerequisite for burial or burial ritual.  Elephants bury their dead.  If anything, burial displays a respect for the body of the living, rather than a belief in the afterlife.

Comment: @cowlinator: The question seems to have been somewhat altered. Maybe psychologists have a word for "refusal to accept one's own mortality" (which imho is essentially what believing in heaven, hell, nirvana, etc. all amount to), but I doubt there will be anything matching what you're looking for. The problem being, of course, that probably the *majority* of all people alive today "suffer" from this "condition".

Comment: I'll observe that we've let far sillier single-word-requests drag on for days.  It is a concept that one would think there would be terminology for, beyond simply "(dis)belief in an afterlife".

Comment: @Nick2253 - well, that isn't something I invented, as the scientific consensus on Cro-Magnons definitely tilts in favor of belief in an afterlife. I thought you might be interested based upon your comment that the concept of an afterlife was *likely* created by the Egyptians. I have no position on the larger question. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva, well said.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can there is no single word for such a denial. For example, had such existed, I am sure that the knowledgeable, well-researched article on the Afterlife at the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy would have used it, or such a term would be used in the Catholic Encyclopedia, but I can find none.

There are more general positions (*atheism*, *materialism*, *non-Dualism*, *...*) which tend to lead to such an assertion, but none so precise as swallowing the desire for a single, obscure word and expressing it with a few common ones as you have done well in your question.

Comment: Kinda curious that there is no term, given that we have about 12 ways to say "atheist".

Comment: I believe "...there is no single word for such..." to be the most accurate answer.  I did find the word "Thanatism" which means "The belief that the mind or soul ceases to exist when the body dies", but it is so obscure, that it's usefulness is limited.  Perhaps if more people started to use the word "Thanatism", it would become more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the term that best fits what you're looking for is *strong atheist*.

The [general categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_and_positive_atheism) are as follows (the definitions change a bit but these are my interpretations):

- Strong atheist ("no god exists")
- (Weak) atheist ("there's no evidence for a god")
- Agnostic ("I'm not sure whether there's evidence for a god")
- Deist ("there's evidence for some kind of higher power / I believe in some kind of higher power")
- Theist ("there's evidence for a specific god / I believe in a specific god")

Comment: Note that one need not believe in a deity to believe that there's an afterlife.  Buddhism, for example, has no conventional deity yet it has the concept of reincarnation, which is arguably a form of "afterlife".

Answer (score 1):

***"Humanism"*** is a term generally used to describe a philosophy that rejects religious superstitions and the presence of an afterlife. If you look it up using this term, you will find many historical references.

Comment: Unfortunately, "humanism" carries a lot of political baggage.